# How to get data from looped radio buttons

Tags: angular, binding, angular-forms

what is the proper way to get selected value from something like this? Trying to get selected values from an array of questions.

```
<ion-card class="card" *ngFor="let question of questions">
      <ion-card-header>
        <ion-card-title>{{ question.data }}?</ion-card-title>
      </ion-card-header>
      <ion-card-content>
        <ion-list>
          <ion-radio-group (ionChange)="radioGroupChange($event)">
            <ion-item *ngFor="let answer of answers['odgovori']; index as i">
              <ion-label>{{ answer }}</ion-label>
              <ion-radio slot="start" value="{{ i }}"></ion-radio>
            </ion-item>
          </ion-radio-group>
        </ion-list>
      </ion-card-content>
    </ion-card>
```

```
radioGroupChange(event) {
    console.log("radioGroupChange", event.detail);
    this.selectedRadioGroup = event.detail;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I have understood, you want to iterate through all the answers selected by a user from a list of questions.

You can do this by maintaining a `selected` option parameter for each question and iterating through it to get the selected options.

A working demo at https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mcq